# Use jar's inside war's WEB-INF/lib as depenendencies

Tags: web-applications, maven, dependencies

The problem is that I would like to use ***.jar** files located inside **WEB-INF/lib** of one of my project's dependencies that comes packaged as war.
I would like to use those files at compile time. Is it possible?

Essantialy it looks more/less like this:

**MyProject** pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
        ................
        <dependency>
            <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...............
</dependencies>
```

**service.war** structure:

```
|
--WEB-INF
     |
     ---lib
         |
         ---lib1.jar   <-  I need this file on compile time for **MyProject**
```

Comment: How has the war file been created? By a multi-module maven build as well? What about the lib1.jar? Is it part of the multi-module build for the war?

Comment: Let's assume it is a "black box". No info how it was build. It just came from nexus index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could think of would be the following:

- Create a module that builds prior to the main one, with the WAR dependency declared.
- As others have said, use the `maven-dependency-plugin`'s ([`unpack-dependencies` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-project-dependencies.html)) to expand the WAR to a temporary location.
- Use the `maven-install-plugin` ([`install-file` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html)) to install the JARs to your local repository. At this time, you'll assign them arbitrary `groupId` and `artifactId` values.

This will take care of setting up the dependencies. As you've now assigned `groupId` and `artifactId` values, you can use them as any other dependency.

This should work, and it's the only way I can think to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these JAR files are proper encoded Java JAR/library files. You can copy and use these JAR files in several other projects. You can use some extractor tool to browse or extract the WAR contents to a local directory.

Comment: I want to achieve this only using Maven configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, you'll need to add these jar files to the BuildPath of your application.
Click with right-button on your project, select BuildPath and then "Configure Build Path". After this, select "Libraries" and then click on "Add External Jars". Select your jar files and that's it.
If you're using Netbeans or another IDE, you have to do something similar.

Comment: I want to achieve this only using Maven configuration

Answer (score 0):

You the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) to copy the dependency war file into an folder with unpack option and copy a file from there out of it in an early lifecycle phase. If you like to use the extracted jar during compile time i'm not sure if you can handle that via maven, cause dependencies will be solved earlier ? But i'm not sure. You can use a system scoped dependency which will be located in the target folder.

Comment: The maven-dependency-plugin will extract/copy the dependencies too late in time. I don't believe this will work.

Comment: Depending on the lifecycle phase which it is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `<dependency/>` with scope "provided" to lib1. I would actually strongly recommend this, if you have lib1 available as a Maven artifact.

Unpacking the war using the maven dependency plugin is also possible, but I wouldn't really recommend this as a remedy to your situation, as you will need to define the lib1 dependency as system typed and I don't believe that will work for you, as the dependency resolution happens right after the interpolation of the POM file, which is too early and the dependency plugin will do pretty much nothing for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a Maven artifact... I would definitely use it as a provided dependency if I could

Comment: I guess you can add it to your artifact repository... Are you using one? (Nexus, Artifactory, etc)...?

Comment: I'm afraid that my permissions do not go that far. This is corporate environment. But I'll try none the less. Thanks for the tip